# How would I populate a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn to use Bootstrap and JQuery. For my current project I am trying to make it possible for a user to interact with Modals. I noticed that the Bootstrap framework offers the use of its specific modal. I got to understand how to implement this, up until the population of such modal.

Say I want to prevent adding the same element over and over (I would just like to make use of one element, to reduce duplicate code), I figured I would want to use JQuery in order to use a single modal and populate it on whatever event is being triggered. For this example I will use buttons and click events.

When I click the button, it should populate the modal assigned to the button with the HTML provided in the click event. I am aware that there are several ways of achieving this, e.g. using AJAX to retrieve a view containing the HTML or by using the JQuery `hide()`, `clone()` and `show()` functions:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //On initialization:
  //Store modal initial values so they can be reset when closed:
  let modalMediumInit = $(".modal.bs-example-modal-md").html();
  let modalLargeInit = $(".modal.bs-example-modal-lg").html();
  let modalSmallInit = $(".modal.bs-example-modal-sm").html();

  //On modal close:
  $(".modal.bs-example-modal-md").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    //Reset modal to initial values:
    $(".modal.bs-example-modal-md").html(modalMediumInit);
  });
  $(".modal.bs-example-modal-lg").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    //Reset modal to initial values:
    $(".modal.bs-example-modal-lg").html(modalLargeInit);
  });
  $(".modal.bs-example-modal-sm").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    //Reset modal to initial values:
    $(".modal.bs-example-modal-sm").html(modalSmallInit);
  });

  $("#my-element").hide();

  //On interaction:
  $(".controls").on("click", "#my-control", function() {
    //Populate modal .modal-body element...    

    //Currently using JQuery:
    let html = $("#my-element").clone();
    $(".modal.modal.bs-example-modal-lg .modal-content .modal-body").html(html);
    $(".modal.modal.bs-example-modal-lg .modal-content .modal-body #my-element").show();

    //Or (AJAX might return some HTML and set it into the html variable):
    html = "<p>A very long string containing all my required html</p>";
    //$(".modal.modal.bs-example-modal-lg .modal-content .modal-body").html(html); //<-- Uncomment following to see effect.
  });
});
```

```css
#my-element button {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="my-element">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Foo
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Foo
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Foo
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="controls">
  <button id="my-control" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
    Populate and open...
  </button>
</div>
<br />
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-md">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal bs-example-modal-md fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Large modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal bs-example-modal-lg fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal bs-example-modal-sm fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez1c9dvx/2/)**

Whenever I use the JQuery method, the provided element to populate the modal with, will be loaded when the page will be loaded (I noticed this element will also appear for a short duration before it will be hidden by provided JQuery code, which to me seems unwanted). Would this be a wrong solution of populating a Bootstrap modal? I have been reading a lot into AJAX lately, should I make use of that in this case, in order to load the HTML into my modal?

Comment: When you write "Populate" you mean show different content on same modal?

Comment: @A.Meshu Yes I would like to use the same modal element for different events (different buttons, have their own event and can use the same modal to fill it with the desired HTML). For example, button "foo" should fill the modal with the text "foo" while button "bar" should fill the modal with the text "bar".

Comment: Actually bootstrap doc provide example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: Could this also be used for entire HTML elements? @A.Meshu I thought/assumed that was only used for inputs and populating these with "small" amounts of data/strings. The amount of HTML I am talking about is at least the size of the amount of HTML provided within the clone method of my javascript. Could you please provide me an example of how to implement this with my HTML (`#my-element`)?

Comment: i think Rhythm Ruparelia answer your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code and created a quick demo. Please check the below code.

**Edit:** I have added data attribute to pass the modal size alongwith the content to be loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
 //On initialization:
  //Store modal initial values so they can be reset when closed:
  let modalContentInit = $(".bs-example-modal-md .modal-body").html();
  
  //On modal close:
  $(".modal.bs-example-modal-md").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    //Reset modal to initial values:
    $("#myModal .modal-body").html(modalContentInit);
    $('#myModal .modal-dialog').attr('class','modal-dialog');
  });
  
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){
    var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var modalContentClass = button.data('content');
    var modalSize = button.data('size') ? ' modal-' + button.data('size') : '';
    $('#myModal .modal-dialog').attr('class','modal-dialog' + modalSize);
    $('#myModal .modal-body').html($(modalContentClass).clone());
    $('#myModal .modal-body ' + modalContentClass).removeClass('hide');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.my-element button {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-element my-element-foo hide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Foo
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Foo
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Foo
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my-element my-element-bar hide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Bar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Bar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        Bar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content=".my-element-foo">
  Modal 1
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content=".my-element-foo" data-size="sm">
  Modal 1 small
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content=".my-element-foo" data-size="lg">
  Modal 1 large
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content=".my-element-bar">
  Modal 2
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal bs-example-modal-md fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this not basically the same, except that you are using a `hide` class instead of jquery's `show()` and/or `hide()` and making use of data attribute to link content to the buttons?

Comment: @Barrosy Yes, this is basically same as your code, but I have modified whats not working in your demo code. What happens in your code is that when you click populate and open, the data is populated in all modals, but when you close that modal, it has the same `modal-lg` class, which again sets the data to initial data, and so you have initial data in all the modals.

Comment: My problem is not the "resetting" part, it's rather the "loading HTML inside a modal" part. I intended in populating all modals, because the modals do not know which size will be used, only javascript should tell. I think my question might be too specific.

Comment: @Barrosy I have updated the answer to load different contents with desired size passed in the data attribute, all in the same modal. Let me know if this solves your case.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why it is important to use the `data-*` attributes which Bootstrap (and also you) show in the examples? Or is the way I am trying to populate the modal also fine (if I would only replace the jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` with classes instead)? I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Barrosy Your method is also fine for populating data. I had used `data-*` attributes, since its the suggested method in [Bootstrap docs example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-related-target).